# Multiple SQL Server Indexes, which ones to keep?

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning

I am looking at my database that several people have worked on. A particular table is responding slowly when queried on a certain join.  I notice some of the parameters of the join are not indexed.  So I look at the indexes that are on the table and there are currently 10 of them, a lot with duplication it looks to me:

```
NonClustered Indexes:

Index1: ManufacturerID, IsDeleted
Index2: IsDeleted, ManufacturerID
Index3: CustomerId
Index4: IsDeleted
Index5: ManufacturerId, IsDeleted, Exported
Index6: ManufacturerId
Index7: ManufacturerId, ModifiedOn
Index8: ManufacturerId, OrderGUID
Index9: SalesRepId

ClusteredIndex: OrderId
```

The 2 columns I do join on are `RepNumber` and `WrittenForRepNumber`.

So my confusion here is why do I have so may indexes that seem to contain the same columns?

Do I need an index for each of these as they look like some of them are geared towards specific queries?

Comment: Take a look at sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats. You want to keep the ones with the highest ratio of read:write. (Why do you have duplicates/redundants? You'll have to ask the person/people who created them.)

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to see what fields are actually being used in indexes, so the statistics might give you a slightly wrong idea about the usage if only the first field is actually used. You can look at plan cache, but that's quite a big task, and only shows those plans that are still in cache

Comment: It sounds like you need a index consolidation project.  Kim Tripp strongly states that having multiple overlapping indexes is not as good as having 1 or 2 covering indexes.  See if you can consolidate.

Comment: so if I have an index for the columns ManufacturerID, IsDeleted, Exported, OrderGUID and my query is only filtering on ManufacturerID would that index work for me?

Comment: Yes it would, because your search condition (ManufacturerID) is the first column in the multi-column index.

Comment: Be aware that filtered indexes and included columns exist.  This can make for more efficient, better targeted indexing strategies.